# Agregar nueva columna a csv con bash

Tags: linux, bash

¿Como podría agregar una columna nueva a un `.csv` desde bash? Tengo este código:

```
INPUT=./student-mat.csv
IFS=','

suspensos=0;
aprobados=0;
notables=0;
sobresalientes=0;
mh=0;

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
 

while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17 col18 col19 col20 col21 col22 col23 col24 col25 col26 col27 col28 col29 col30 col31 col32 col33
do

    if [[ "$col31" -ne "G1" || "$col31" -ne "G2" || "$col31" -ne "G3" ]]; then
        if [[ "$col31" -ge 0 && "$col31" -lt 10 ]]; then
            echo "$col31 $col32 $col33 Suspenso";
            suspensos=$((suspensos + 1));
        elif [[ "$col31" -ge 10 && "$col31" -lt 14 ]]
        then
        echo "$col31 -> Aprobado";
        aprobados=$((aprobados + 1));
        elif [[ "$col31" -ge 14 && "$col31" -lt 17 ]]
        then
        echo "$col31 -> Notable";
        notables=$((notables + 1));
        elif [[ "$col31" -ge 17 && "$col31" -lt 19 ]]
        then
        echo "$col31 -> Sobresaliente";
        sobresalientes=$((sobresalientes + 1));
        elif [[ "$col31" -ge 19 && "$col31" -le 20 ]]
        then
        echo "$col31 -> MH";
        mh=$((mh + 1));
        fi
    fi
              
done < $INPUT
```

Necesito crear una nueva columna llamada `Calificación` por ejemplo. Y en el bucle añadir si es suspenso, aprobado ... dentro del `if` en cada registro. Y devolver un nuevo `csv` con esta nueva columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es tener una variable `result` donde almacenes si el estudiante está `aprobado|notable|suspenso` y luego al final de las condiciones hacer un `append` al fichero resultado.

Por ejemplo, teniendo el siguiente `csv`:

```
Adrian,19
Antonio,9
```

Hacemos lo siguiente (explico en el código con comentarios):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare result

# Leemos el csv que deseamos procesar usando de separador la coma
# Almacenamos cada columna en las dos variables 'name' y 'score'
while IFS=, read -r name score
do
    # Con condicionales determinamos el resultado, sea 'aprobado|suspenso|...'
    if [[ "$score" -lt 10 ]]; then
        result="Pass"       
    else
        result="Failed"
    fi
    # Comprobamos los datos (opcional)
    echo "Name: $name, score: $score, result: $result"
    # Almacenamos en el fichero resultado. 
    # Mergeamos las líneas usando el delimitador ',' y sustituímos los valores
    printf '%s\n' $name $score $result | paste -sd ',' >> results.csv
done < test.csv
```

De esta manera al ejecutar el script:

```
$ -> bash csv_process.sh 
Name: Adrian, score: 19, result: Failed
Name: Antonio, score: 9, result: Pass
```

Vemos que ha hecho el append correctamente:

```
$ -> cat results.csv 
Adrian,19,Failed
Antonio,9,Pass
```

Comment: Nota: sería bueno colocar el nombre de la variable con referencia a un significado real. `col1`, `col2` aportan un significado muy bajo en comparación a `nombre`, `nota`.